# error: Failed to initialize NSS library on RHEL 7.3 after installing libvirt package

Tags: rhel, kvm, libvirt

I want to install libvirt and libguestfs-tools on RHEL 7.3 KVM host. But I'm facing the following problem:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y libvirt
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

My Python version is 2.7.5 .

Comment: This looks that probably some install script (written in python?) couldn't run, because the python package, which would contain the "ts" python package, doesn't exist on your system. It is possible, that it is a bug in the libvirt package (it should depend on this package, but it doesn't). Look after, which package provides this "ts" (its name makes probable, that it is a quote general package), and install it.